approaches to Atiyah Singer index theorem
What is a "modern treatment" of Atiyah Singer index theorem? Is there a point of view involving 6 functor formalism or condensed mathematics? I want to learn Atiyah Singer theorem from an "abstract" point of view, what is a good way to start? Does it make sense to read some classical references?
